# This localhost page can’t be found :Phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, apache, phpmyadmin

after resolving the issue of Apache and Mysql, suddenly I am facing the issue as Localhost not found.

```
No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost/phpmyadmin
```

Issue I have resolved for MYSQL is :

```
# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client] 
# password       = your_password 
#port            = 3306 
port            =8111
socket          = "C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
```

## Here follows entries for some specific programs

```
# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
#port= 3306
port = 8111
socket = "C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
basedir = "C:/xampp/mysql" 
tmpdir = "C:/xampp/tmp" 
datadir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
```

I have port to 8111 in both the cases as this was the only option which helped me out while running MYSQL.

Any help?

Comment: `No webpage was found` usually means error `404`. So your phpmyadmin listening different port or different ip or has different url path or not installed... many reasons...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may be related with Your Localhost Port. rather than typing http://localhost/phpmyadmin type like 'http://localhost:PortNumber/phpmyadmin'.
check Your port Number at 'httpd.conf' file. these are the basic

1. Listen 'Your Port number like 80 or else
2. ServerName localhost:'Your Port number like 80 or else

Comment: oh , it was silly me. Forgot to mention the Port Number